# Overlay widgets, designing a chess board in Qt

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt-designer

My idea is that I want to create a background label with an image of my board, and overlay a grid from labels on top of it, where I will use the code to upload images of my shapes. But I don't understand how I can overlay multiple widgets on top of each other in Layout.

Are there any ways to overlay widgets on top of each other in Layout, or do i need to approach the design of a chessboard in a fundamentally different way?

Comment: Consider using the Graphics View framework https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/graphicsview.html. If you later decide to support features like animation of the pieces, it will be much easier.

Comment: Another (basic) alternative is to override [`QWidget::paintEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent) and use the painter primitives provided by `QPainter` to draw the chess board and labels yourself. As stated by Passerby, `QGraphicsView` is better suited if you need features such as zooming, ....